# Exe I created by autohotkey compiler are crashing after sometime

Tags: autohotkey

```
; PLAY
+F1:: ;the + means shift
Send {Media_Play_Pause}
return

; MUTE
+F2::
Send {Volume_Mute}
return

; Decrease Volume
+F3::
SoundSet -5
return

; Increase VOLUME
+F4::
SoundSet +5
return

; Previous
+F5:: 
Send {Media_Prev}
return

; Next
+F6::
Send {Media_Next}
return
```

***This is the code and is made to use Shortcuts for MediaKeys. but the exe just closes after some time.***

Comment: I tried to compile it. Didn't get any error, had it running in background and used it for spotify. Cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: The code you edited is the Accurate. Mine was messed up because it was a copy/paste from Editor. And yes my code has no Errors, problem is that my compiled Exe is crashing after sometime. It works perfectly before it crashes.

Comment: For me, it also works perfectly after compiling, even after intense usage. Sorry.

Comment: What version and Setting for AHK are you using. I'm using the v1.1.21.03 Unicode 32-Bit

Comment: well I am using 1.1.09.02 AutoHotkey ANSI 32-bit, downloaded on christmas 2012 (according to the details of AutoHotkey.exe)

Comment: I figured that my EXE only works for single use. It processes my request one time then it Closes. What can i Add in the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76381/discussion-between-rishabh-pandey-and-blauhirn).

Comment: Did you convert the script to an EXE using [Ahk2Exe](https://github.com/fincs/Ahk2Exe)?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions. You could create a shortcut to the executable with compatibility options. Something like 'execute as Windows XP sp2' could work better than just starting the executable from the shell. You could also add a small delay in your script after each Send command.

Comment: I tried in Compatibility Mode(Windows Feature).I don't see how a Delay can help. No luck.

Comment: The delay could change how commands are processed by the internals of AutoHotKey. Commands like 'Send' or 'Sound Set' might not fully complete their cleanup phase before the script resumes execution to the next command. From experience I know that adding a short delay (50-100 ms) after a SendKey command helps avoid those kind of bugs. From the description you give, I'd suspect you run into a memory problem.

Comment: oh ok... then it didn't crash it just exited gracefully. I haven't done a lot of macro programming with autohotkey, sounds like return ends the procedure. In a regular language I'd just put a loop around the key polling.